# Loading a module in a bash script on an HPC cluster

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, cluster, hpc

I am submitting the following bash script with `qsub` on a standard university cluster,

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -cwd           # Set the working directory for the job to the current directory
#$ -pe smp 1      # Request 1 core
#$ -l h_rt=1:0:0  # Request 1 hour runtime
#$ -l h_vmem=100M   # Request 1GB RAM
module load xorg-utils/X11R7.7
module load mathematica/13.1.0
math < topaz43 > topaz43master
```

but the script is returning an error after queuing for a while, with `jade4.e374195` reading

```
/var/opt/sge/node-b00a-001/job_scripts/374195: line 6: module: command not found
/var/opt/sge/node-b00a-001/job_scripts/374195: line 7: module: command not found
/var/opt/sge/node-b00a-001/job_scripts/374195: line 8: math: command not found
```

The modules usual load properly when I run them on the login nodes, running

```
module load xorg-utils/X11R7.7
module load mathematica/13.1.0
math
```

will start Mathematica as usual. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Those commands most likely are defined as shell functions (or aliases) – so that they would be able to update the shell's environment ($PATH and stuff), which an external script placed in /bin wouldn't be able to do.

Only interactive shells automatically load such definitions from /etc/profile and /etc/bash.bashrc; non-interactive Bash processes (those running a script) will not do so. You have to explicitly source the initialization scripts with `. /etc/profile` and so on.

(If 'module' is an alias rather than a function, you'll also need to enable alias expansion in non-interactive mode using `shopt -s expand_aliases`.)

Comment: Am I just not cd'ing into the right directory? It should be simple to just load a standard module then run the script?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "standard module" in shell scripts. The entire 'module' system is custom to your cluster.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to load modules in a non-interactive session, and though I can easily load them interactively, when I use the queuing system, no modules load and the documentation just provides no help.